# Should I enable BITS on my Sql Server 2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008

i have a web farm with iis7 boxes running w2k8 and a single sql server running w2k8 also. all x64bit. We're on a private Gigabite LAN.

Should I have BITS enabled for

1. each iis7 box?
2. sql server box?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BITS is only needed if you plan on having the server allow other services to upload or download files by using the BITS client.  Examples would be a WSUS server would need the BITS Extensions installed.

Normally you wouldn't need this enabled.

Comment: Cheers. The reason i raised this question wast this text => "preserve the responsiveness of other network applications". So i wondered if that ment it would enable any network traffic to run more efficiently .. somehow. But nope.. so all good! Thanks again Mr Denny :)

Comment: No problem.  Happy to help.